# Bash summing numbers in a file

Tags: bash

I have a file which looks like this:

```
aaa 15
aaa 12
bbb 131
bbb 12
ccc 123
ddddd 1
ddddd 2
ddddd 3
```

I would like to get a sum for each unique element in the left side like this and also calculate the rounded percentage each of this represents out of the total:

```
aaa 27 - 9%
bbb 143 - 48%
ccc 123 - 41%
ddddd 6 - 2%
```

How would I accomplish this in BASH?

Comment: why bash? `awk` can handle it in a super easy way -- you can find tons of questions like this

Comment: Python even easier...

Comment: It's part of a larger script which is written in bash already. I guess awk wouldn't look bad so if you have suggestions with awk I would be happy to look at them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Since I cannot find any proper duplicate, I am posting an answer. Feel free to report a good one, so I will delete my answer and close as duplicate.</sub>

```
awk '{count[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in count) print i, count[i]}' file
```

This creates an array `count[key]=value` that keeps track of the value for a given key. Finally, it loops through the values and prints them.

It returns:

```
aaa 27
ccc 123
bbb 143
ddddd 6
```

To show percentages, just keep track of the total sum and divide accordingly:

```
awk '{tot+=$2; count[$1]+=$2} 
      END {for (i in count) 
           printf "%s %d - %d%%\n", i, count[i], (count[i]/tot)*100
      }' file
```

So you can get:

```
aaa 27 - 9%
ccc 123 - 41%
bbb 143 - 47%
ddddd 6 - 2%
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I don't think Python would be easier :P

Comment: I added the percentage requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for Bash, here's a Bash≥4 solution (needs Bash≥4 for associative arrays):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -Ai sums

while read -r ref num; do
    # check that num is a valid number or continue
    [[ $num = +([[:digit:]]) ]] || continue
    sums[$ref]+=$(( 10#$num ))
done < file

for ref in "${!sums[@]}"; do
    printf '%s %d\n' "$ref" "${sums[$ref]}"
done
```

The output is not sorted; pipe through `sort` (or use a sorting algorithm) to sort it.

---

So now you added the percentage requirement! I hope you're not going to edit the question further adding more and more stuff…

Once we have the associative array `sums`, we can sum the sums:

```
sum=0
for x in "${sums[@]}"; do ((sum+=x)); done
```

and print the percentage:

```
for ref in "${!sums[@]}"; do
    printf '%s %d - %d%%\n' "$ref" "${sums[$ref]}" "$((100*${sums[$ref]}/sum))"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

And a solution for `bash` 3, without associative arrays:

```
while read key value
do
    keys=$(echo -e "$keys\n$key")
    var=data_$key
    (($var=${!var}+$value))
    ((total=total+$value))
done < input_file

unique=$(echo "${keys:1}" | sort -u)
while read key
do
    var=data_$key
    ((percentage=100*${!var} / total))
    echo "$key $percentage%"
done <<EOF
$unique
EOF
```

Changed to use indirect variable references, rather than the more traditional `eval`.

Comment: Hoping that there are no values of the form `$(find / -exec rm -rf {} + 2> /dev/null)`. Don't use `eval` on user input!!!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Sound advice. I have changed my solution accordingly.